# How to define limits of integration for a triple integral in SciPy using tplquad?

Tags: python, scipy, integral

I cannot understand how to approach defining the limits of integration for a triple integral in Scipy with the `tplquad` function. I am using the book *Learning Scientific Programming With Python* By Christian Hill and trying to solve [problem E8.14](https://scipython.com/book2/chapter-8-scipy/examples/the-volume-of-the-unit-sphere/):

> The volume of the unit sphere, 4π/3, can be expressed as a triple integral in spherical polar co-ordinates with constant limits:

[image]

My attempt to evaluate this integral:

```
import scipy.integrate as integrate
#define the integrand
f = lambda r, theta, phi: r**2 * np.sin(theta)
#integrate with tplquad
V_unit_sphere, _ = integrate.tplquad(f, 0,1,0,np.pi,0,2*np.pi)
V_unit_sphere
```

My output was 165... clearly not equal to 4pi/3.

Hill's Solution:

```
from scipy.integrate import tplquad
In [x]: tplquad(lambda phi, theta, r: r**2 * np.sin(theta),
                0, 1,
                lambda theta: 0, lambda theta: np.pi,
                lambda theta, phi: 0, lambda theta, phi: 2*np.pi)
Out[x]: (4.18879020478639, 4.650491330678174e-14)
```

I do not understand why Hill defined the integrand in the order of `phi, theta, r` when the integral is taken the other way around, and I do not understand why even though all the limits of integration are constants, they must be defined as depending on some variable. I also do not understand why the limits of integration for theta are dependent on theta, and why the limits for phi are dependent upon both phi *and* theta.

Answer (score 0):

Although the solution in the textbook works, I don't think it is the correct way to solve this problem.

According to the documentation of [`scipy.integrate.tplquad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.tplquad.html), the integrated function should be defined as `f(z,y,x)`, and it will be integrated in that order (`z`, `y`, then `x`). In your example, the order of integration is `r`, `theta`, `phi`, so the function should be `f(r, theta, phi)`, as you defined it.

The limits are defined in the opposite order, so the first two limits are the limits of integration for `x` (`phi` in your case), followed by `y` (`theta`), and finally `z` (`r`). Because the order of integration is `z`, `y`, then `x`, we can have the limits for `z` be functions of `x` and `y`, and the limits for `y` can be functions of `x`. In this case, the limits are all constants, so we can just provide constants (Hill used functions that returned constants, which is more general but has the same result).

That said, I believe the code should be:

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import tplquad

volume = tplquad(lambda r, theta, phi: r**2*np.sin(theta),
                 0, 2*np.pi,            # limits of integration for phi
                 0, np.pi,              # limits of integration for theta
                 0, 1)                  # limits of integration for r

print(volume)           # (4.18879020478639, 4.650491330678174e-14)
```

Moral of the story: **Just because it works and was written in a book doesn't mean it is the right way to do it.** Always test things yourself and read the documentation.